# Convert datetime column time zonefrom CET to CEST in R

Tags: r, datetime, timezone

I have two columns with DateTime (e.g., 2021-03-01 01:30:26) and Temperature from start of March to end of May, however the time is all in UTC+1, and I need the DateTime to be converted to CEST (summertime; UTC+2) at the appropriate time shift (which is October 28th 2 AM turns into 3 AM).

Anybody know how to code for this in R?

Example data:

```
#dput(head(Re1292))
Re1292 <- structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1615899000, 1615899600, 1615900200, 1615900800, 1615901400, 1615902000), 
                                              class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                         Temp = c(5.9, 5.1, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

#              DateTime Temp
# 1 2021-03-16 12:50:00  5.9
# 2 2021-03-16 13:00:00  5.1
# 3 2021-03-16 13:10:00  4.9
# 4 2021-03-16 13:20:00  4.9
# 5 2021-03-16 13:30:00  4.9
# 6 2021-03-16 13:40:00  4.9
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that adding `tz = Copenhagen` within lubridate fixed this problem!
E.g.

```r
mutate(DateTime=lubridate::ymd_hms(DateTime, tz="Europe/Copenhagen"))
```